# how to change the submit button appearance?

Tags: html, css

I have this plain submit button appearance in my html code

```
<input type="submit" name="pay now" value="pay" />
```

I wish to make the submit button look like this

```
<a href="#"><img src="images/shopping-cart/check-out-btn.png" border="0" /></a>
```

but should stick with its submit type

how to do that ?

Comment: useful link : http://www.tyssendesign.com.au/articles/css/styling-form-buttons/

Comment: solved this problem by <input type="image" src="blah blah blah">

Answer (score 8):

You should use CSS for that:

```
input[type="submit"] {
    background: url(images/shopping-cart/check-out-btn.png);
    width: 200px; /* width of image */
    height: 50px; /* height of image */
    border: 0;
}
```

You should probably use a more specific selector though.

Comment: customizing submit button via css is not a good option since its not cross browser..

Comment: @GauravShah: Erm, what browser are you using that doesn't support CSS?

Comment: I don't mean to say that browser doesn't support css.. what I mean is say you have disabled button , try customizing and opening in IE , Chrome and safari and see the difference..

Answer (score 7):

A nice way to do this is using the button element.

```
<button type="submit"><img src="images/shopping-cart/check-out-btn.png" border="0" /></button>
```

It works just like a regular input with type=submit, but you have much more freedom.

Answer (score 3):

You can make an image into a `submit` button by setting the `type` attribute of the `input` element to `image`:

```
<input type="image" src="/path/to/image.png">
```

For more information, read the [`image` Button State section of the HTML specification](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#image-button-state-type-image).