# Calling a servlet in a button click

Tags: jquery, html, servlets

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default button-colorcancel fontcancel">Cancel</button>
```

I want this button to call a servlet when I click it, do I need to use jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do it without using javascript is to use a form and set the servlet as the action:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp

[Servlet returns "HTTP Status 404 The requested resource (/servlet) is not available"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731377/how-to-call-servlet-from-html-form-in-jsp-file-without-getting-http-status-404)

Then you can modify your submit element to match what you have on your current button:

[how to change the submit button appearance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814844/how-to-change-the-submit-button-appearance)